# Most effortless way to design a spreadsheet?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, information-graphics

I am often given either spreadsheets or word documents with lists of things that I then have to style in a graphics program of my liking. I need to create a sort of infographic like informative graphic.

My main issue with this is that often the information or order changes later on and it takes a lot of time to re-enter the whole spreadsheet again.

Maybe this is farfetched, but is there a way to load a numbers spreadsheet into a graphics program such as photoshop, illustrator, sketch app and have it fill certain prefixes/dummy content?

Comment: I think the least effort solution is to pay someone else to do it :-)

Comment: Have you tried using Data Merge?

Comment: You can copy paste spreadsheet data from Excel to InDesign and use InDesign [table/cell styles](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/85014/indesign-how-to-edit-table-text-cells-and-rows-all-at-once). You don't mention the use of InDesign in your question though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in-design can read tables. Or you can just use a script to inject the values no big deal. Or if you prefer to use illustrator or Photoshop and no scripting, then you can make tables in inDesign and place the inDesign page into the other application that will update when your inDesign does.

I am in my day to day work astonished how bad tools graphic designers use for info-graphics. And even the tools they have are way under utilized. Updating a table is pretty trivial, but nothing says you can not update graphics from that data too. Its possible to color objects from data no problem. It is also possible to rope in tandem with a scientific potting tool etc,.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about PS and AI for this job.

There's a couple of ways to bring spreadsheets into InDesign, which sort of automatically transforms these to tables and then there's a ton of ways for you to quickly setup some basic formatting or more advanced styles you can then re-use for future work. This can get very detailed so just research this for a bit on Youtube and soon you'll be doing this :)

[image]